# SQL Server Enterprise Manager 2005 - stored procedures not showing up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When using SQL Server Management Studio from SQL Server 2005, I can connect to an instance of SQL Server 2000... but none of the stored procedures show up. Is there some trick to allow SQL Server Enterprise Manager 2005 to properly talk to SQL Server 2000 databases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the account that you're logging in as does not have access to execute the stored procs.  If it doesn't have access to use a stored proc, SQL Server Management Studio 2005 won't show it (regardless of it you're connecting to a SQL 2000 or 2005 server)

Comment: You're welcome.  Your websites and writings have been a big help to me, so I'm happy to have a chance to return the favor.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a 2005 Enterprise Manager. Instead there's a Management Studio, which shows Databases/database/Programmability/Stored Procedures (and it's looking at a 2k database).

Answer (score 1):

I have my SQL Server Management Studio hooked up to two SQL Server 2000 Servers and the stored procs show up under programmability on the database I'm accessing.

P.S. I just thought it would be amusing to see who was tied to their computer on New Year, why are you not partying like the rest of the world? :oP

Comment: you too. It turns out it was a trigger, stored under a table, not under "programmability." And indeed it was hardcoded with "2008" grrrrr

Comment: Ah - yes a trigger wouldn't be under programmability... but that wasn't what you asked.  Good you got it fixed so quickly though.  Now that you've changed it to 2009 you can rest until next year :P